# How to load the data from odoo to a front end website in odoo8?

Tags: odoo-8, odoo-website

I want a sample code for loading the data from odoo to a front end website.
For example I want to load the customer name in front end website in Odoo 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create  the controller
2. Fetch the record on controller using  `request.env['res.partner'].sudo().search([('customer','=',True)])`
3. Render the result on the template

   ```
   class MyController(http.Controller):
   @http.route('/my/customers/', auth='public')
   def my_customers(self, **kw):
       customers = request.env['res.partner'].sudo().search([('customer','=',True)])
       return http.request.render('mymodule.customerlist', {
           'customers': customers
       })
   ```

Here

1. **mymodule** is the module name.
2. **customerlist** is the template name .
3. {
               '**customers**': customers
           } is the dictionary which contain list of object of **res.partner**
4. **/my/customers/** is url on which you will get the template filled with the customer data

You can also read the list of resources at

1. [how to accessing the data in odoo website](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/website.html#accessing-the-data)
2. [how to building eCommerce-web-application in ODOO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473443/odoo-9-building-ecommerce-web-application/36594085#36594085)

Hope it may help in your case.